# Core Data with TableView giving assertion error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

After a hour of going through codes and editing after removing fetchedresultscontroller delegate and section part of tableviewdatasouce, the tableView properly showed the items:

CoreDataTVC:

```
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSections:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return [[self.frc.sections objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
    {
        if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return [[self.frc sections] count];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
        if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return [self.frc sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
    }

    -(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return [[[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
    }

    -(NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
    {
        if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return [self.frc sectionIndexTitles];
    }

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    if(debug==1) NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            if(!newIndexPath)
            {
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }else
            {
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I am really a beginner to ios programming, so i still don't get what i am doing wrong to get the error! Any help in the above code would be a good learning experience for me!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: if you only want your code work, you only need to implement `controllerDidChangeContent`, and in there, call `[tableView reloadData]`.

In detail, for partial updating in tableView, it require number of rows after updating is **equal** to it's desired number. that is:
the original number, plus insert cells and minus delete cells.

In your error, after updating, your fetchResultsController have 5 objects.
but you only call insert once. this can happen before your `controllerDidChangeContent` called, fetchResultsController's dataSource change again.

I've noticed your fetchResultController's `ManagedObjectContext` is same as the one you create model items. so for each item created, fetchResultController respond to `ManagedObjectContext` change, instead of batch change when context saving. this should be the reason why you only have one insert for tableView.

If you really want to animate each row changing, you should create a copy dataSource for tableView, and add, delete, update it according to fetch delegate notify, instead of using `fetchedObjects` directly. In this way, you can ensure table view's number of rows is always equal to your dataSource count, and won't change by others.

Comment: what exactly should i change if i want to use the delegate methods?

Comment: @hengecyche only implement `controllerDidChangeContent`, and in there, call `[tableView reloadData]`. Don't imp other delegate method.

Comment: @hengecyche if your app is a single thread app, your can see the Xcode new project template with CoreData enabled.